# iterating the list of objects returned from hibernate ref cursor

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jdbc

I have a storedprocedure call from hibernate as below. The ref cursor result is not an entity. The result set would be list of objects like firstName, lastName, middleName, info1, info2, address1, address2.

```
query = em.createStoredProcedureQuery("TEST.VIEW_REPORT")
            .registerStoredProcedureParameter("iErr", BigDecimal.class,ParameterMode.OUT)
            .registerStoredProcedureParameter("vErrMsg", String.class,ParameterMode.OUT)
            .registerStoredProcedureParameter("reportId", BigDecimal.class,ParameterMode.IN)
            .registerStoredProcedureParameter("subReportId", BigDecimal.class,ParameterMode.IN)
            .registerStoredProcedureParameter("studentId", BigDecimal.class,ParameterMode.IN)
            .registerStoredProcedureParameter("studentName", String.class,ParameterMode.IN)
            .registerStoredProcedureParameter("reportCur", void.class, ParameterMode.REF_CURSOR)
            .registerStoredProcedureParameter("headerCur", void.class, ParameterMode.OUT);

List<Object> reportResults = query.getResultList();
for(int i=0; i<reportResults.size(); i++){
     Object obj = reportResults.get(i);
     System.out.println("----"+obj.toString());
}
```

Here println gives '[Ljava.lang.Object;@7faa080c' which is again an object with firstName, lastName, middleName..

How do I iterate this listObject in for loop? Whats the efficient way to get the values?

Update:
The output of the cursor would be a list of the return values of this query say for example 32 rows.

```
select
            pa.first_name as first_name,
            pa.last_name as last_name,
            pa.MIDDLE_INITIAL as middle_name,
            bi.info1 as info1,
            bi.info2 as info2,
            bi.address1 as address1,
            bi.address2 as address2
        from
            studentInfo pa
```

Comment: You need to cast your Object to the expected one

Comment: can you show us what your Procedure return ?

Comment: @YCF_L updated my question. My procedure returns a iist of values of the query executed. This is a sample one but its a join of multiple tables and result set consists of 10-12 columns and returns multiple rows. Output is not an entity.

Comment: @YCF_L I tried to cast the obj as foll dto -> ReportResultsDTO r = (ReportResultsDTO)obj; Getting the foll exception Exception is [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to abc.model.ReportResultsDTO

Comment: Did you tried the solution of Alex Rudenko?

Comment: I have tried the same but object is a DTO and not an entity. So got this exception Error message is {}.javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: abc.model.ReportResultsDTO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create a POJO representing the data returned by the stored procedure and provide this class in `createStoredProcedureQuery("TEST.VIEW_REPORT", ReportPojo.class)`.

Then `query.getResultList()` will return a typed result which you can use.

```java
query = em.createStoredProcedureQuery("TEST.VIEW_REPORT", ReportPojo.class)
            .registerStoredProcedureParameter("iErr", BigDecimal.class,ParameterMode.OUT)
            .registerStoredProcedureParameter("vErrMsg", String.class,ParameterMode.OUT)
            .registerStoredProcedureParameter("reportId", BigDecimal.class,ParameterMode.IN)
            .registerStoredProcedureParameter("subReportId", BigDecimal.class,ParameterMode.IN)
            .registerStoredProcedureParameter("studentId", BigDecimal.class,ParameterMode.IN)
            .registerStoredProcedureParameter("studentName", String.class,ParameterMode.IN)
            .registerStoredProcedureParameter("reportCur", void.class, ParameterMode.REF_CURSOR)
            .registerStoredProcedureParameter("headerCur", void.class, ParameterMode.REF_CURSOR);

List<ReportPojo> reportResults = query.getResultList();
reportResults.forEach(System.out::println);
```

```java
class ReportPojo {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String middleInitial;
    private String info1;
    private String info2;
    private String address1;
    private String address2;
// getters/setters/toString

}
```

Comment: i tried this. However ReportPojo  is not an entity. Its just a DTO.Error message is {}.javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: abc.model.ReportResultsDTO